# Definition of s-lim? (context: Trotter product formula)

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, mathematical-physics, stochastic-analysis, semigroup-of-operators

I am searching for a definition of "s-lim", a notation I am seeing used sometimes in the statement of the Trotter product formula (for instance in Barry Simon's book Functional Integration and Quantum Physics e.g. p6, or here [though weirdly formatted] in the [online Encyclopedia of Math](https://www.encyclopediaofmath.org/index.php/Trotter_product_formula).  From context, I assume that this is supposed to refer to a limit in the strong operator topology, but since I can't find an actual definition, I wonder if anyone can confirm or else point me to the correct interpretation?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, "s-lim" here means "limit in the strong operator topology".

Comment: Wow! Thanks, talk about instant gratification! :-)

Comment: You're welcome.  You can click the check mark by my answer to mark it as "accepted".

Comment: You can see this also used for "stochastic limit" in probability theory.  So anyone using it should say what it is.  Even worse, in that reference: writing it as $s-\lim$  (so that it looks like a subtraction) instead of $\mathrm{s}$-$\lim$ is a genuine error.

Comment: Aha!  Thanks, that explains the "s", then.  Yes, the way they formatted it in the encyclopedia entry was really messed up.